# Mouse Interaction

Tags: c

How can I make mouse interaction with c environment in windows platform?

Comment: This depends on your operating system/graphics environment and/or the libraries you're using.

Comment: Not a real question... OP needs to put more work into this and do his/her research a bit more... voting to close this...

Answer (score 5):

Just ANSI C does not have the ability to do GUI applications. You need to use GUI libraries to perform mouse interactions.

Libraries such as Windows API, XWindows (there are tons more, these are the "core" basic libraries) are what you need.

What platform are you developing on?

Comment: why my question is invalid, I have search so many internet site but I have not find any appropriate explanation.  
I have more work for this.  
so please help me out from this problem.  
otherwise provide me explanation at stackoverflow.

Comment: @Vibhakar - The reason your question was marked as invalid is that you are asking quite a large question. Writing a GUI program isn't a couple lines of C code. Look at this website for some pointers on how to get started: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming